# How to convert this pytorch based D3NET into ONNX file?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

Recently I am training some depth image with this model[Model's Github](https://github.com/DengPingFan/D3NetBenchmark)
I trained the model and get the 3 best.pth, and followed the tutorial [Pytorch Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html)
to created the code below. In the end I have to convert 3 all models, but for practice I just convert 1 first.

`Export_onnx.py`

```
import torch.onnx
from model.RgbNet import MyNet as RgbNet

pretrained_models={'RgbNet':'./eval/pretrained_models/RgbNet.pth', 'RgbdNet':'eval/pretrained_models/RgbdNet.pth' , 'DepthNet':'eval/pretrained_models/DepthNet.pth' }
model_rgbd=RgbdNet()
model_rgb.load_state_dict(torch.load(pretrained_models['RgbNet'])['model'])
model_rgb.eval()

#Dummy Input 1 = RGB Image, Dummy Input 2 = Depth Image
batch_size = 1 
dummy_input1 = torch.randn(batch_size, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float32)
dummy_input2 = torch.randn(batch_size, 1, 224, 224, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float32)
input = (dummy_input1, dummy_input2)

torch.onnx.export(model_rgbd.cpu(), (input,), "Model.onnx")
```

And when I run this code, it returned nothing and no error code. Only showed some scanning network detail in terminal like below
[image: Problem]

Could anyone help me solve this issue....pretty thanks alot!!!